# phantomjs wait till the redirection happens..?

Tags: phantomjs

I have a phantomjs script that checks whether my login to website works or not. It basically hit the website URL and grep the string "where to?" on my website landing page. If found then it returns TRUE else FALSE.

Currently my script is failing because, it's not waiting until my website loads. Since my website has not loaded yet, it couldn't find the string "where to?" and hence fails.

So, is there a way we can put some **sleep** in phantomjs, so that it sleeps for 2 mins or so and then check for string "where to?".

My current code that waits for redirection:

```
// ensure that form redirects will be executed
    function() {
        try {

            page.evaluate(
                function () {
                    if (document.getElementById("pageResponse") != null) {
                        document.getElementById("pageResponse").submit(); 
                    }
                }
            );
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    },
```

Some how its not working. It still doesn't wait it the redirection happens to the actual page.

Regards,
Rohith

Comment: Please, show your current script code.

Comment: @Vaviloff   added the code..!

Comment: No, we need the *minimal working example*, this won't work if I try to run it with my PhantomJS.